# mysql - How to query maxima grouped by 2 attributes?

Tags: mysql

So I've got a table that holds 2 attributes `base_id` and `sub_id` which form the primary key. The table holds a list of values and a date from which the value was valid like so:

```
 base_id | sub_id | validity_start_date | value
---------+--------+---------------------+-------
 1       | 1      | 1970-01-01          | 50
 1       | 1      | 2000-01-01          | 55
 1       | 2      | 1970-02-02          | 50
 1       | 2      | 2000-02-02          | 55
 1       | 3      | 1970-03-03          | 50
 1       | 3      | 2000-03-03          | 55
 1       | 4      | 1970-04-04          | 50
 1       | 5      | 2015-05-05          | 66
 1       | 5      | 2015-06-06          | 70
 2       | 4      | 1970-01-01          | 80
 2       | 4      | 2015-01-01          | 75
```

My goal is to find the latest valid `value` and `validity_start_date` for unique primary keys like so:

```
 base_id | sub_id | validity_start_date | value
---------+--------+---------------------+-------   
 1       | 1      | 2000-01-01          | 55
 1       | 2      | 2000-02-02          | 55
 1       | 3      | 2000-03-03          | 55
 1       | 4      | 1970-04-04          | 50
 1       | 5      | 2015-06-06          | 70
 2       | 4      | 2015-01-01          | 75
```

To help you help me, the create code:

```
CREATE TABLE `rikai_test` (
  `base_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sub_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `validity_start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `value` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`base_id`,`sub_id`,`validity_start_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `rikai_test` VALUES (1,1,'1970-01-01',50),(1,1,'2000-01-01',55),(1,2,'1970-02-02',50),(1,2,'2000-02-02',55),(1,3,'1970-03-03',50),(1,3,'2000-03-03',55),(1,4,'1970-04-04',50),(1,5,'2015-05-05',66),(1,5,'2015-06-06',70),(2,4,'1970-01-01',80),(2,4,'2015-01-01',75);
```

Grouping by `base_id` and `sub_id` OR getting the absolute maximum is no problem, but I fail to combine those to to get the grouped maxima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common solution to this problem is to use a derived table to find the maximum per group and use that table in a join like this:

```
select r.* 
from rikai_test r
join (
    select base_id, sub_id, max(validity_start_date) max_date 
    from rikai_test
    group by base_id, sub_id
) a on r.base_id = a.base_id 
   and r.sub_id = a.sub_id 
   and r.validity_start_date = a.max_date
order by r.base_id, r.sub_id;
```

The result would be:

```
base_id sub_id  validity_start_date value
1       1       2000-01-01          55
1       2       2000-02-02          55
1       3       2000-03-03          55
1       4       1970-04-04          50
1       5       2015-06-06          70
2       4       2015-01-01          75
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88a3eb/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll look at this first thing tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it either with a left join where is null, or with a group-concat-trick.

The first one is in the kind "show me those data who have no successor with the same base_id, sub_id combination", which translates to "show data where not exists someone with bigger date".

```
select d1.* 
from rikai_test d1
left join rikai_test d_not 
     on d1.base_id = d_not.base_id 
     and d1.sub_id = d_not.sub_id 
     and d1.validity_start_date < d_not.validity_start_date
where d_not.base_id is null
```

and needs of course a not-null-column (which you have). It works best of course if you index base_id, sub_id and if you have not too many values in one combination. It could be even improved with `where not exists (select ...)`.

The other one is [CORRECTED] of type "give me the biggest date per group, but just let this date bring it's relatives to the party". So we bind together this date and the real value, let mysql maximize this (so the ordering data has to be at start of the concat'ed pair) and when both have made it to the max then we can split and separate them.

```
 select base_id, sub_id, substring(constring, 1, 10) as start_date, substring(constring, 11, length(constring)
 from (select base_id, sub_id, max(concat(validity_start_date, value)) as constring group by base_id, sub_id ORDER BY constring) as innerselect
```

which should be quite fast even for bigger results.

Comment: I've really look into your solutions and try to understand them. I can't really tell if your's is the better answer, I simply accepted it because I am able to understand it easily =)

Comment: Use what you (+ coworkers) better understand, and when one solution gets too slow just know there are other ones. ;-)

Comment: Yeh, I just always feel bad when I get multiple good answers and can't tell which one is the "best" and thus accept the "wrong" one =) But stackexchange is pretty self correcting in that matter, if anyone looks this up in a year or so, either someone posted a new state of the tech answer or the "best" one was upvoted =)

Comment: Well, don't feel bad about this at all, in the StackOverflow-way it was wrong anyway to answer this again, but I just wanted a few coins with no effort and was to lazy to search the best and official duplicate to this kind-of-standard question. And jpw's answer is the "SQL" way anyway, and two upvotes is nice for the little effort. So have a nice week!

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from rikai_test
where validity_start_date in
(select max(validity_start_date)
from rikai_test
group by base_id, sub_id)
```

[SQL Fiidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84095/23/0)

Comment: Be very Careful! if you have the same date for different base_id, sub_id, and for one it is max and for other it is in the middle, then this gives too many and wrong results.

Comment: Yes, but in this situation this result is ok

Comment: You mean for the view data you can see here? This is just example, and a date is a long unit of time, so very probably there will be time collisions. Even the worse if they come in a year or two and at rare occasions!